# Access csv file stored on Heroku server

Tags: heroku

I am writing to a CSV file through my heroku app. The csv file is updated around the clock, and periodically I need to pull it down to check the updates. How can I pull that csv file down to check any updates to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to save any data on your Heroku dyno.  Dynos are ephemeral and can be restarted or replaced daily.  Additionally, traffic is load balanced across your application dynos - there's no way to share updates to this file across requests.

If you have persistent data, you should put it in a database or a distributed file store like Amazon S3.

For example, if you're logging events you should consider writing the events to a SQL database or redis.  When you need to pull the CSV formatted report, you can generate it on the fly, or in the background.  When the CSV is generated, you can store it in S3 and prepare a link for anyone who needs it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll get started on setting it up to dump into a DB then.